# Unable to use getStaticProps in _app.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am using next.js and trying to do the following:

1. Fetch basic data related to user data in _app.js. The data includes a title (for the navbar) and some social links (for the footer).
2. Pass down that data to other components like Footer and Navbar at the build time (for static site generation).

For that I've exported the `getStaticProps` from app.js file. But it doesn't seem to work. Here is my app.js.

```
import Layout from "../src/Layout";
import "../styles/globals.css";
import getAppData from "services/appData";

export default function App({ data, Component, pageProps }) {
  console.log(data, "data"); // data is undefined here
  return (
    <>
      <Layout data={data}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    </>
  );
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  console.log("working on it dude"); // this message is not logged in console (terminal)
  let data = await getAppData(CLIENTID);
  console.log(data); // data is undefined here as well
  return {
    props: {
      data: data,
    },
    revalidate: 60,
  };
}
```

And the Layout.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Head from "next/head";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";

// Contexts
export const toggleMenu = React.createContext();

export default function Layout({ data, children }) {
  // States
  const [showNav, setShowNav] = useState(true);
  const [showFooter, setShowFooter] = useState(true);

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      </Head>
        <toggleMenu.Provider
          value={{ showNav, showFooter, setShowFooter, setShowNav }}
        >
          {showNav ? <Navbar data={data.navbar} /> : null}
          {children}
          {showFooter ? <Footer data={data.footer} /> : null}
        </toggleMenu.Provider>
    </>
  );
}
```

`data` is undefined even if I pass a simple string as props in getStaticProps.

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  return {
    props: {
      data: "something",
    },
    revalidate: 60,
  };
}
```

Knowing the fact that we can't use getStaticProps in a file other than a page, I have to use it in _app.js only and pass it down to `<Layout data={data}/>` component (if no other solution exists).

I can use getStaticProps in index.js page as well but Navbar and Footer are used in it's parent component i.e, . Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Custom `_app` does not support `getStaticProps` - see https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app#caveats. You'll have to use `getInitialProps`, or fetch the data with `getStaticProps` on each page instead.

Comment: I tried `getInitialProps` but it doesn't work as well. Infact none of these functions are being even called as I'm not getting any console messages from `getInitialProps` or `getStaticProps` in the terminal.

Comment: And I can't fetch data using these functions in Navbar or Footer components as they are not pages.

Comment: Add the code you have for `getInitialProps`

Comment: It's exactly same as `getStaticProps`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As its already mentioned above _app.js doesn't support `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps` , you can only use `getInitialProps` inside _app.js

```
export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  console.log(pageProps.data, "data"); 
  return (
    <>
      <Layout data={pageProps.data}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    </>
  );
}

App.getInitialProps = async () => {
  let pageProps = {};

  try {
    let data = await getAppData(CLIENTID);
    pageProps["data"] = data;
  } catch (error) {}

  return { pageProps };
};
```

Comment: How to implement this in a dynamic route?

Comment: @Arul For dynamic routes, you can still use getServerSideProps or getStaticProps. Do keep this is mind, getServerSideProps or getStaticProps will only work for nextjs pages directory routing. Won't work with new nextjs App router

Comment: @Inder can I get some resource to read more on that, I have been looking for clear documentation but some concepts are not sufficiently explained, thanks!