# Static page rendering(similar to getStaticProps) on nextJS app router

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, react-server-components

Im using nextJs for a while.
Now initiating a new project using the app router (where traditional behavior is called the pages router).
In the pages router, I could export getStaticProps to build pages on run time.
Which is very ideal for data that doesn't vary often (e.g portfolio website )
From [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/get-static-props):

```
If you export a function called getStaticProps (Static Site Generation) from a page, 
Next.js will pre-render this page at build time using the props returned by getStaticProps.
```

When I export a getStaticProps in page.tsx file (app router).
Im getting the following error:

```
"getStaticProps" is not supported in app/. 
Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching
```

Going to the docs page suggested in the error message left me extremely confused.
It was talking about caching, when I want to generate a **static page**.

Is this behavior possible using the new app router? and if so how?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72069612/unable-to-use-getstaticprops-in-app-js

Comment: The _app file is related to the old pages router. It's not what Im asking :)

Answer (score 0):

> In the App Router, Next.js would try to prerender everything just like in Pages Router

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/51860